# How does the attribute value bind to the scope in Controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the developer guide from angularjs, and I have some question about the code.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
angular.module('docsTimeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
  }])
  .directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var format,
          timeoutId;

      function updateTime() {
        element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
      }

      scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
        format = value;
        updateTime();
      });

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
      });

      // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
      timeoutId = $interval(function() {
        updateTime(); // update DOM
      }, 1000);
    }

    return {
      link: link
    };
  }]);

<div ng-controller="Controller">
  Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr/>
  Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
</div>
```

How does "format" in my-current-time="format" bind to the format model? Because my-current-time="format" is not my-current-time="{{ format }}". So how does

```
function updateTime() {
   element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
}
```

know about $scope.format in the Controller? the "format" variable should refer to the newly created variable in the link function, but I don't see how that variable binds to $scope.format in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

So (as far as I know) attributes in directives can work the following ways:

1. By two-way-bound expression (`'='` used in the isolate scope object;
   expression must be left-hand-value/assignable)
2. By one-way-bound expression (`'&'` used in the isolate scope object ;expression doesn't have to be a left-hand-value/assignable)
3. By interpolated string (`'@'` used in the isolate scope object)
4. By string value (usually from the attributes object, could also be from the element or jQuery or anything else - but it's no longer part of the "angular way" at that point; isolate scope object may or may not exist).  If this option is taken the directive-programmer may also choose to to `$observe` the attribute, or, in this case, `$watch` it.

Point being if I have `$scope.a = 123` in my controller somewhere, depending on how the directive/attribute is wired by the programmer up I may do `my-attribute="a"` OR `my-attribute="{{a}}"` OR the attribute may not accept anything except whatever string is actually in the view.

In this case, the string is `$watch`-ed by:

```
// attrs is the attributes object I mention in bullet point 4.
// myCurrentTime is camel-case for hypenated-snake-case my-current-time; 
// Angular does this conversion for you automatically.
scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
  format = value;
  updateTime();
});
```

Whenever a `$digest` cycle occurs (generally every time something changes) that involves that `scope`, the supplied `function` will be executed, which then updates the time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Are you saying scope.$watch is watching the model derived from the value of my-current-time. i.e format? attrs.myCurrentTime = format. so $watch finds a scope variable that has a name of "format" and watches its behavior?

Comment: "so $watch finds a scope variable that has a name of "format" and watches its behavior?" change "behavior" to "value" and yes.  And $watch can "deeply" watch objects/arrays or just watch their reference, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

The format below is still the local variable format. The newFormatValue, is the new value of your $scope.format:

```
  ...
  scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(newFormatValue) {
    format = newFormatValue;
    updateTime(value);
  });
```

The **attrs.myCurrentTime** in this case is the value of your **my-current-time attribute**, which is "*format*".

The first parameter of the *$watch()*, is an expression evaluated against **the $scope context**; so, when angular evaluates "format" it really sees "$scope.format". **When the result** of the watched expression changes, the listener (the second parameter) gets executed.

You need to store the 'newFormatValue' because every 1000ms you have this:

```
  ...
  // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
  timeoutId = $interval(function() {
    updateTime(); // update DOM
  }, 1000);
```

It is calling updateTime(). And format can be undefined on some time. So, setting the format with the newFormatValue updates the local format variable and be used every 1000ms.

*How does "format" in my-current-time="format" bind to the format model?*
Because your html has this:

```
<input ng-model="format">
```

The ng-model directive will somehow call **$digest()** in the process. When a $digest() happens it will check all the watched expressions. If the result of the watched expression changes the listener gets executed. In your case:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, listener)
```

The listener is your:

```
function(value(){}
```